# I cannot create a project or create a key

Tags: google-places-api

I have a Google Apps account, created several years ago (what's referred to now as the G. Suite). This is the free service, and I do not have a billing account setup.

I have been using it, for at least 10 years, with my own domain, and I have several accounts set up under. I identify it as business account.

I am trying to get an API key, so I can experiment with the Maps API. When I try to create a project, I'm getting an error message (not very descriptive, only that an error was encountered).

Is this because I don't have a billing account setup, with a credit card? I thought I did not need to do what when if I m using the standard API access.

Any idea what's going on? I have an app ready to go for testing purposes. As an aside, I find the developers Dashboard, and the entire UI pretty confusing, but that's probably because I am not used to it.

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps to get an API key:

Go to the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=placesandroid&reusekey=true).

Create or select a project.

Click Continue to enable the Google Places API for Android.

On the Credentials page, get an API key.

Note: If you have an existing API key with Android restrictions, you may use that key.

From the dialog displaying the API key, select Restrict key to set an Android restriction on the API key.

In the Restrictions section, select Android apps, then enter your app's SHA-1 fingerprint and package name. For example:

BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75

com.example.android.places-example

Click Save.

Above article is from [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup) source